# Write data across cassandra multiple data centers

Tags: cassandra

I would like to understand the following,
Suppose we have two data centers DC1 and DC2, each with two nodes. 
Now I have formed a token ring with the order DC1:1 - DC2:1 - DC1:2 - DC2:2.
Let us assume, I have not configured my replicas across DCs.
Now my question is, if I write a data into say DC2, will the key be mapped only to the nodes in DC2 or will it get mapped to any of the nodes in the token ring?

Answer (score 1):

If your keyspace replication options are set to

{DC1:2}

(I assume this is what you mean by replicas not being configured across DCs.)  Then data will only be stored on DC1 because implicitly the replication factor is zero for DC2.  You can write data to any node (DC1 or DC2) and it will be forwarded.  This is because, in Cassandra the destination of writes does not depend on which node the write was made to.

If, however, you use

{DC1:2, DC2:2}

then all data will be written to all nodes, again regardless of where the write is made.